# confused about adding fields to a table

Tags: database-design

I have those information and I have to build a database:

a Person have name,lastname,marital status, mail,phone number,profession,field of activity(the field of activity of the person not of the company =>his skill),company name

I want to know the fields: company name and field of activity, should I add them to the table Personne or put them in another table?

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you have more than 1 organisation or skill per person.

Assuming you have 1 organisation and 1 skill per person you'll get something like this

```
Table Person
 person_id
 organisation_id
 skill_id
 etc.
```

And corresponding tables for organisation and skill of course.

If you have more then 1 per person you have 1-n-1 relationship:

```
Table Person
 person_id

Table skill
 skill_id
 text
 etc.

Table skill_person
 skill_id
 person_id
```

Same thing for organisations. For background on this stuff google 1-n-1 relationships, database normalisation and entity relationship diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to store data that can be repeated into separate tables for flexibility, avoiding redundancy and ensuring data consistency. This is called [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and it is probably the most fundamental principle in relational database design. So, yes, store *companies* and *skills*, and most likely also *profession* and *field of activity* in separate tables and use [foreign keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) to refer to these using foreign keys.